Type or name space couldn't be found

Assets\VoiceCommand.cs(8,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
'KeywordRecognizer' could not be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\VoiceCommand.cs(27,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace
name 'PhraseRecognizedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a
using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\VoiceCommand.cs(8,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
'KeywordRecognizer' could not be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?)

I try to find the open source library but fail to do so. so provide me the better and working solution for this.

Please edit the post so that it contains a minimal reproducible example.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can refer to the documentation for help with these. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer.html Do you have using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech; at the top of your script? Are you targeting the Windows platform?

First thing to try if you using Visual Studio, place the cursor on top of the error line then Ctrl + . (dot). This will open a drop down with potential fixes. If you are only missing the using statement, then you can add it from there.
